# checks all checkboxes in the DataTable including hidden rows

Tags: jquery, datatable, webforms

I'm trying to make a function that checks all checkboxes in the DataTable, including hidden rows.
Here's the html code for the "checkbox" column:

```
<div class="usersTable" id="userTable">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="customersList" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" name="selectall" id="selectall" class="selectall"/></th>
                <th width="200">val1</th>
                <th width="80px">val2</th>
                <th width="70px">val3</th>
                <th width="450">val4</th>
                <th width="60px">val5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Submit button:

```
<input type='button' value='select all' id='selectallboxes' name='selectallboxes' />
```

And the JQuery code that doesn't work:

```
$(function () {         
    otable = $('#customersList').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aLengthMenu" : [ [10,20,50,100,1000], [10,20,50,100,1000] ],
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "aaSorting":[],         
        "iDisplayStart": 0,
        "sAjaxSource": "filename",
        ....

$("#selectallboxes").click ( function () {
        alert(dt.fnGetNodes().length + ' is total number')
        var selected = new Array();
        $('input', dt.fnGetNodes()).each( function() {
                $(this).attr('checked','checked');
                selected.push($(this).val());                       
        } );
         // convert to a string
        var mystring = selected.length;
        alert(mystring);
})
```

Comment: What happens if you change `$("#selectallboxes").click` to `$("#selectall").click`?

Comment: @darshangs That would only create a click event for the actual checkboxes not the select all button, the problem is the logic in the click event not the handler

Comment: @DavidBarker My mistake. I was reading the question incorrectly.

Comment: I have to add this comment that above code works only for the first page and alert return the number of elements in this page only.

Comment: When you say page do you mean each paginated dataTable page?

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
$("#selectallboxes").click(function () {
    var selected = new Array();
    $(otable.fnGetNodes()).find(':checkbox').each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('checked', 'checked');
        selected.push($this.val());
    });
    // convert to a string
    var mystring = selected.join();
    alert(mystring);
});
```

`.length` gives you the length of the array. I've used `join()` to join the array into a string. DataTable's `.fnGetNodes()` gives you all the rows in the table including hidden ones.

Comment: I guess because  "bServerSide" is true,I have to handle it on server side. I think in this case all data doesn't fetch at first.

Comment: +1 for your this line of code $(otable.fnGetNodes()).find(':checkbox').each, you save my day

Comment: Since DataTables v1.10, `$(otable.fnGetNodes())` should now be: `$(otable.rows().nodes())`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this should be what you're after, this will find all the current page `<tr>`'s and cycle through them using dataTables _ API. You can change the filter to suit your needs to select different rows should you want to, this is all documented in the datatables documentation.

```
$("#selectallboxes").click ( function () 
{
    var selected = new Array();

    // Use the _ function instead to filter the rows to the visible
    var data = oTable._('tr', {"filter":"applied"});

    $.each(data, function(key, index)
    {
        var input = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');

        input.attr('checked', 'checked');

        selected.push(input.val());
    });

    // convert to a string
    var mystring = selected.length;

    alert(mystring);
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work unfortunately. The result is the same with past.

Comment: just spotted, you're putting the <input> in a <th> tag, they would need to be in <td>'s for ``fnGetNodes()` to pick them up

Comment: I added this line to the frist line of my function in order to getting better result:
   **alert(otable.fnGetNodes().length + ' is total row number')**
but this return the number of elements on the first page!

Comment: Actually, it returns the total number of nodes in the `<tbody>` not just the nodes displayed, that's what that function does, you can run a check for `$(this).is(':visible')` to see if it is displayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$("#selectallboxes").click ( function () {
     var selected = [];
    $('input:checkbox', otable).each( function() {
        selected.push($(this).prop('checked', true).val());                       
    } );
    // convert to a string
    alert(selected.join());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

fnGetNodes() will give only the rows that are visible, there is an extension to get the hidden rows due to pagination fnGetHiddenNodes(), but that will work with jquery datatable version 1.9, there is update for the same in jquery datatable 1.10 but this is not working.
You can store your data received from the ajax request in an array and then based on the condition of the checkbox click event re-draw the table with the data and input(checkbox) with selected attribute.